# Pdf Viewer gradle problem in android studio

Tags: android

when i add this :  implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2' in gradle build
then run this and then showing error that is given below: Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$1 found in modules core-1.5.0-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.5.0) and support-compat-25.3.1-runtime (com.android.support:support-compat:25.3.1)

Comment: Looks like the `barteksc` libs still not using AndroidX? Therefore it conflicted (duplicate) with your own dependencies in `androidx.core`

Comment: how can i solve this ?plz tell me

Comment: Can you please update your question with your app level `build.gralde` code ?